# How to detect whenever app comes to foreground in android

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, foreground

I have read alot about `how to detect when app comes to foreground` but unable to find any satisfactory answer. Most of them are using onResume() and onClose() methods and keeping count etc

> I am working on a crypto-currency app and I have to ask for passCode
>   whenever app comes to foreground, which is very critical in my case.
>   It must ask for passCode every time.

So that is why I want to assure that isn't there any method to detect this in android by default if not then what is the best approach?

Comment: no `onResume()` is called multiple times not only when app comes to foreground

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now you can add a LifecycleObserver to your app when it's created to detect when your app goes to foreground/background.

```
class MyApp : Application() {

    private lateinit var appLifecycleObserver : AppLifecycleObserver

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appLifecycleObserver = AppLifecycleObserver()
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(appLifecycleObserver)
    }
}


class AppLifecycleObserver() : LifecycleObserver {

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onEnterForeground() {
        // App entered foreground
        // request passpharse
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onEnterBackground() {
        // App entered background
    }

}
```

Comment: what is `ProcessLifecycleOwner`?

Comment: a class that provides lifecycle for the whole application process
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner

Comment: actually I am unable to import it. I don't why

Comment: I had to add `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"` in app gradle to reference `ProcessLifecycleOwner`

Comment: its working fine when app goes to background and comes to foreground but there is a lill problem that `onEnterForeground()` is being triggered when I open a new activity. How can I resolve that?

Comment: That shouldn't be happening if you are registering the LifecycleObserver in your application class. Could you update your question to show how are you registering the observer?

Comment: Actually I have added it in `baseActivity` which I am inheriting in every activity perhaps thats why its happening. I have found a way: I am checking value of a boolean value which is true only when `onEnterBackground()` is called. So thats how I can check if value is true when `onEnterForeground()` called then it means that app was in background before that.

Comment: Thanks for clean and efficient approach, I believe only a genius can come up with simple solution!

Comment: np, I had to do the same research a couple of weeks ago, I couldn't find the links to a more detailed explanation but I'm glad to help.

Comment: This is not working with androidx, so I would appreciate it if someone could update the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You should do the passcode in the onResume() method as that would be the last method called prior to the activity running again.

Comment: It will be called even when I will start an activity from another activity, and surely this is not what I want

Answer (score 1):

You could use onWindowFocusChanged.